# Snowflake Python Connector - fetch_pandas_all() is really slow with less than 25k records

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, database-cursor

I'm using fetch_pandas_all function to retrieve result of a query that takes less than 2 sec in Snowflake (checked activity in UI) but the function itself takes like 30 seconds - we are talking about a query that returns about 25k records.

Versions that I use:

```
snowflake-connector-python 3.1.0
pyarrow                    10.0.1
pandas                     2.0.3
```

Code snippet:

```
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    #cursor.arraysize = 50000

    query = union_query
    logging.info(f"Executing UNION query")
    cursor.execute(query)
    logging.info(f"Fetching UNION query result")
    df = cursor.fetch_pandas_all()

    cursor.close()
```

Setting arraysize has no effect on performance.

OUTPUT:

```
2023-08-22 14:07:43,633 | root | INFO | Successfully connected to Snowflake
2023-08-22 14:07:43,633 | root | INFO | Executing UNION query
2023-08-22 14:07:43,831 | root | INFO | Fetching UNION query result
2023-08-22 14:08:16,246 | root | INFO | Finished fetching. Returned 26,625 rows
```